# How does GItHub know which PR's belong to a release?

Tags: github

When you create a GitHub release, it has a feature to auto-generate "release notes" which list all the PR's belonging to a Release. But how does it know which PR's belong to a Release?

I thought it would be something like: All the PR's from the tagged commit you supplied when creating the Release, back to the the last commit when a Release was created

But what we are seeing is if I create two different tags at the same commit, and create two separate GitHub releases, each using one of those tags, each Release includes the same PR's. I would expect the last Release created to show no PR's because no commits were added between those two back-to-back Releases.

Comment: yeah there is some kind of strange behavior. I've tested it in a example repo in which I created four tags v0.0.1 - v0.0.4 and four releases v0.0.1 - v0.0.4. What is kind of strange in the changelog it compares v0.0.3 with v0.0.1 and for v0.0.4 with v0.0.2.
it seems that GitHub only compares to a tag in from which changes are made so for me tag v0.0.3 was only a duplicate of v0.0.2 thus means release v0.0.2 and v0.0.3 containing the same changelog information I guess...